# Compress/optimize multiple jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, selector

I have multiple lines of selectors and I want somehow to compress/optimize the code, that look like this:

```
$('div#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(10)').addClass('col-grey');
$('div#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(11)').addClass('col-grey');
$('div#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(12)').addClass('col-grey');
$('div#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(16)').addClass('col-pink');
$('div#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(22)').addClass('col-grey');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Separate them with comma: ```$('#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(10),#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(11),#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(12),#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(22)').addClass('col-grey');
$('#tableMainBodyDiv_Iesiri table tr td:nth-child(16)').addClass('col-pink');```

Comment: simple for loop?